# Is the Aleppo Codex hekdesh?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, tanach, text, hekdesh

Every 10 or so pages of the Keter, the words קדש לה' לא ימכר ולא יגאל are written across the top.  These words are based on [Vayikra 27:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.27.28), which discusses hekdesh.

Does that mean somebody actually donated the Keter to hekdesh?  I think we can safely conclude from the [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.8.4), who personally used it, that it's not completely forbidden to use, but are there restrictions on its use beyond the kedusha that all sifrei kodesh have?  If so, do those restrictions apply to the [online scan](http://aleppocodex.org/newsite/index.html)?

Comment: Lots of old manuscripts have similar inscriptions indicating a curse on people who misuse it or something. I don't see any reason to think they were more than symbolic.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'd ask the same thing on all of them.  If the person who wrote the inscription owned the manuscript and phrased it in neder language, why wouldn't that take effect as a neder?

Comment: @Heshy- for starters, there's a machlochet as to whether or not a written neder takes effect at all

Comment: @JoshK Maybe they also said it out loud.  Maybe it was a standard thing to do and then write it in the manuscript as a reminder, like [Maaser Sheini 4:10-11](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Maaser_Sheni.4.10-11).  I don't know if there's any historical evidence for that or if it's the default assumption, but it's plausible.